# Geometry Nodes to Mesh - Separate Shapes in Mandala

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have created a mandala using Geometry Nodes and then converted to a mesh.
[image]

After converting and filling:
[image]

The end result I'm looking for is something like this:
[image]

What I can't figure out is how to split each pyramid to a separate shape. Right now the entire thing is one object.
I tried using <kbd>P</kbd> with "Separate Selection" in the flat form, and that works, but then I have to do it one by one and poke each individually. The rest of the P options didn't do anything.
How do I split the entire flat mesh to each shape in the mandala in one go, or do that in the poked shape?

I have done this about a year ago but cannot remember how, so I know it's possible:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: pls provide blend file how you get to your "converting and filling". thx.

Comment: I hope this works: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lm1ilJzt7LfGCMogsrz_jD4BDZvdq5O0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Shirko, sorry, you misunderstood me. I asked for your result after "converting and filling". You sent the blend file with just the easy GN setup.